# How to write install tag in makefile?

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile

```
install: bank
if[ -d $(INSTDIR) ];\
then\
cp bank $(INSTDIR);\
echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)";\
else\
echo "Sorry";\
fi
```

I am writing this script in install tag and this error is coming. Can anybody suggest what I did wrong,.

```
error->
if[ -d /home/salman/Desktop ];\
then\
cp bank /home/salman/Desktop;\
echo "Installed in /home/salman/Desktop";\
else\
echo "Sorry";\
fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/sh: -c: line 6: `fi'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question: add four spaces in front of every code line, in a separate paragraph. And show more of your `Makefile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
install:
        if [ -d $(INCLUDE_INC) ] ; then\
                echo "Is a directory $(INCLUDE_INC)";\
        else\
                echo "Sorry";\
        fi
```

1. One tab before the if, else and fi.
2. Two tabs before the echo statements.
3. "\" slashes to keep the command in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between 'if' and '['. The syntax error is due to space missing.

Comment: sorry wayne i tried that one also but same error is coming.

Comment: Scripts in Makefile requires tab for indent. Check make manual.